# Select empties after clicking outside AngularJS/bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to AngularJS and currently i have a problem with a select.

I'm editing existing user info, and when it comes to choose a profile (perfil) or enterprise (empresa) it starts blank, that is not a problem, the problem is that if I click outside any input, the  selected option vanishes FROM THE VIEW (i've checked and the data did bind). 
Example:

[image: Profile selected]

[image: After Clicking outside any input (i can click and fill other inputs or selects with no problem)]

The code it's here:

```js
/*This is how i obtain the profiles from a table, this returns an array of objects which contains "codigo","descripcion","idPerfil"*/
function listaperfiles(){
            var listaperf= portalServicios.listaperfiles(mntusuarioCtrl.id).$promise;

            listaperf.then(function(respuesta){
                mntusuarioCtrl.perfiles=respuesta;
            });

            listaperf.catch(function(respuesta){
                $log.error("Perfiles Error");
                $log.error(respuesta);
            });
        }

/*This function obtains a list of registered users from a table, this contains "nombre","apellidos","codigo","clave","idUsuario","tblPerfil","tblEmpresa", "estatus","email", "seleccionado" is just the user selected fomr that list that is going to be modified or deleted*/
function listaUsuarios(data){
            var listausr = ssmeServicios.obtenusuarios(data).$promise;

            listausr.then(function (respuesta){
                $log.info(respuesta);
                mntusuarioCtrl.usuarios=respuesta;
            });

            listausr.catch(function(respuesta){
                $log.error(respuesta);
            })
        }
```

```html
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="perfil" class="col-sm-3 control-label" style="padding-right: 10px">Perfil:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                             <select required="true"
                                    id="perfil"
                                    ng-model="mntusuarioCtrl.seleccionado.tblPerfil"
                                    ng-options="opcion.descripcion for opcion in mntusuarioCtrl.perfiles">
                                 <option value="" select hidden/>
                             </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

it's just a minor nuisance but it has been bothering me!

If needed i can provide more info about the code or anything.

Thank you for your time!.

Comment: Could you create a plunker reproducing the error?

Comment: What is `select hidden` in your option value ??

Comment: @Amit: i use it to hid a blank option that appears in the select.

Comment: here is my plunker attempt to replicate my app, i can't get the modal to work, but it is somewhat like this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/X5zBiEiCvy3EQvVV41kn)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a `plunker` with a select example, modified with a similar structure to your code:

http://plnkr.co/edit/sOqtxVz2utHUXhw0hOQd

Hope it helps! If not, please explain a little bit better your solution. A plunker could help a lot!

**EDIT:**

Now with your plunker I can see your error. Here is a forked plunker working good: http://plnkr.co/edit/sm1DhanxJpLJ4Yrkhucx?p=preview

Angular looks for object equality to bind it with your syntax and 2 objects are equal only if they point to the same reference. So it couldn't load the selected value. However, using `track by` solves this issue.

Comment: your plunker works perfect, but in my app it doesn't work, maybe it's something in my configuration.

I was trying to replicate it in plunker, but i can't make the modal  work properly, ill just post it for reference.
[link](http://plnkr.co/edit/X5zBiEiCvy3EQvVV41kn)

Comment: Oh, yes, my bad.
The problem i had was with the modal that reloaded the lists since i told it to do so on focus. problem solved.